# ASP.net 4.0 Fragment Caching using Custom Cache Provider generated key

Tags: asp.net, caching

I have implemented a disk based Custom Cache Provider which works fine except from one problem. When i use the provider in aspx Pages the generated key is of the from "a2/../../default.aspx" which is fine. When I use the same provider in User Controls the generated key is of the form "lfffffff40e80...." and this is fine till the application pool recycles. Then for the same user control a similar key is generated (but not the same) meaning that the cashed user control cannot be accessed with the new key and a new entry is generated in the Disk Cache for the same user control.

Is this the way Custom Cache Providers work with User Controls? How can I generate the same key for the User Control when the application pool recycles?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that there is a way to control how cache keys are created - for a user control, its an involved process that included combining multiple hash codes and/or including stack trace hash etc. Because invariably, hash code of some factory object is used in the computation of cache key, you will get a different key in fresh app-domain (after app pool recycle) because hash code of object would differ.

As such I don't see any major issue even if new cached copy is created after app pool recycle - because you need to tune that time as well as (you cannot have tow frequent app pool recycles because application start code will need to be run after each recycle).

BTW, you can have a [Shared](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.partialcachingattribute.shared.aspx) copy of cache for multiple instances of user controls on different pages.